# $( window ).on( 'orientationchange') firing on desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im seeing $( window ).on( 'orientationchange') firing on desktop on Chrome , is that expected behaviour or does that mean some other part of the code im working with is actually dispatching this event?

Comment: When do you see it firing?

Comment: when resizing the browser

Comment: I don't see this happening for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ9Hx/

Comment: I don't experience it either, but looking through the source, it doesn't look impossible...

Comment: @RocketHazmat first off, change your console.log to an alert().  Then change the sizing to a portrait size (height greater than width) and you will experience the issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/sJ9Hx/1/

Comment: @maccettura: `alert` is a terrible debug tool, `console.log` works fine (and better).  I did, see the log though when I made the browser's width more than its height.

Comment: It saves you from having to keep the console open and weed through all the other things being written.  In this case an alert() is a nice visual indicator (which stops you from being able to do anything without acknowledging).

Comment: @maccettura: My console is pretty much open 99.9% of the time, plus I can have it filter errors from logs :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Fair enough  :)

Comment: @maccettura: Thanks, though, for pointing out how to make the event trigger.  I was resizing the browser left/right, but not up/down ;-)

Comment: I updated my answer with some new ideas.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>As far as I can tell the javascript is only detecting when the height grows greater than the width and vice versa.  So when you change your browser size to a height > width it will launch the event.  This seems to be the expected behavior of the function, I am not sure how to circumvent that for your use.</strike>

**EDIT:** I found that when you check the window.orientation property when the event is fired you can see that it is still set to landscape.  Maybe try filtering your landscape only code by putting it inside an if statement?  See http://jsfiddle.net/sJ9Hx/2/

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function (e) {
    if(window.orientation == 0){
        alert("Portrait");
    }
    else{
        alert("Landscape");
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The orientation changes when the height and width values are altered!

Lets say when `840x600` becomes `600x840` you can say that the device's orientation has changed. That way the OS would detect and would execute the co-responding function. But wait, there are many other methods of detecting that, using sensors too!

If you're getting that this event is getting executed, then of-course there is some sort of JS file there! Which is causing this event. For this, you need to check the JavaScript code and see how it detects the orientation change and then do what so ever action regarding that!